# Overwriting the hashCode() and equals() method in Java

Tags: java, equals, contains, hashcode

As the heading suggests, my question has something to do with overriding the hashCode() and equals() method. However, this is also not completely true, I just did not know another way to summarize my question.

I have an object `Label` that contains multiple components, one of which is a `List` that contains multiple objects of type `Node`. An example of `Label` would be: `[(n1, n2, n3), (n4, n5)]`. I want to store all unique `Label` objects generated in a `LinkedHashSet`. However, this is not working as expected. Suppose that the `LinkedHashSet` currently contains the `Label` described above, and that we now generated a new `Label` called `other`  which turned out to contain the same nodes as the already added label, thus also `[(n1, n2, n3), (n4, n5)]`. Since it has the same list of nodes, the other components in `Label` are also identical. I won't explain here why, just assume that it is, because that is the case. However, when checking if the `LinkedHashSet` already contains the `Label` it returns `false`, since the objects have different object ID's.

One approach would be to write a for-loop over the `LinkedHashSet` and compare the new label with all labels in the `LinkedHashSet`, but that would be very expensive in terms of running time, so I am looker for a cheaper option. Any suggestion is welcome!

Another approach would be to adapt the `equals()` method, but this was not working out, since I also have to adapt the `hashCode()` method and I do not know what to change this to to get this working.

Comment: Have either `hashCode` or `equals` been overridden on `Label`?    Unless these are overridden, the default implementation of `hashCode` will be used, which corresponds to object identity.

Comment: Take a look on this article: https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: It's not clear what the difference is between your question and the standard "how do I override equals and hashCode in Java?"

Comment: Caching the hash code of `Label` objects would provide good efficiency.

Comment: @kaya3 The OP is not sure that overriding `equals` and `hashCode` is actually the solution to his (or her) problem.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Yes, but it is the solution, and if the question were edited to be more focused then it would probably be asking why the OP's attempts to override equals/hashCode didn't work.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn What does OP stand for? I know how to implement the standard equals() and hashCode() methods. However, I changed the equals() method to check whether the list of nodes of both objects are the same, and if so, it should return true, otherwise false. I have difficulties with changing the hashCode() function properly.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to "for-loop over the `LinkedHashSet` and compare..." Detecting duplicates is what the `LinkedHashSet` is supposed to do. In order to do that, it needs appropriate implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`.

You probably understand that you need to implement `equals` such that it returns true when a `Label` is "equal to" another `Label`, however you define that. If two labels are equal when they have the same nodes, then yeah, you pretty much have to look at all the nodes and check that they're the same.

That leaves `hashCode`. You must implement `hashCode` to be consistent with `equals`, that is, if two labels are equal, they must have the same hash code. That's because `LinkedHashSet` is going to use the hash code to determine the bucket in which a `Label` resides, and then use `equals` to compare the new `Label` with the ones that already exist in bucket. If two labels are equal but generate different hash codes, `LinkedHashSet` won't be able to detect them as duplicates.

The simplest thing to do would be to incorporate the hash codes of all the nodes into the hash code of the `Label`. Something like:

```
int hashCode() {
    int hc = 1;
    for (Node n : allMyNodes) {
        hc = hc * 31 + n.hashCode();
    }
    return hc;
}
```

If there are lots of nodes and it's unlikely that two labels will share the same node unless they're "equal," you could just use the hash code of the first node, instead of rummaging through them all.

Comment: Since Java 7+ you usually don't need to deal with the complex implementation of hashCode yourself, you can call Objects.hashCode(...) with the list of fields.

Comment: Also here you don't need to create the hashCode of the list yourself as the list implementation probably as an hashCode implementation. So you can do ```return Objects.hashCode(allMyNodes)``` and that's all.

Comment: You're correct in both cases, and in fact the `List` interface defines `hashCode` to be the function that I wrote. (Though I made a mistake, it should be initialized with 1, not 0.) But I thought it was useful to show what is actually happening.

Comment: Fixed the function.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn thank you for this clear explanation! I like your suggestion for the hashCode method, but I am afraid that it is not sufficient for my method. As in, I have to be super careful, because I can have multiple labels with the same nodes, but in different orders/parts of the list, thus requiring different hashCodes. If the equals() method returns true, and the hashCode() returns false, will the new label then be added to the linkedHashSet? That would have my preference.

Comment: The way it works is that if the hash codes are different it assume the objects are different and so it will add them to the set, if the hash codes are the same it will call the equals method to check if they are actually the same. If the order of the nodes doesn't matter they should be in a set instead of a list, a list is specifically made so that the order does matter.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope thank you! That was the answer I was hoping for ;). In my case, the order of the nodes matters.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing equals(...) and hashCode(...) is the right approach here. Usually people use their IDE to generate those methods for them, here is what this would look like with Java 7+:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Label label = (Label) o;
        return Objects.equal(nodes, label.nodes);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(nodes);
    }
```

If you have multiple fields this become:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Label label = (Label) o;
        return Objects.equal(nodes, label.nodes) &&
                Objects.equal(other, label.other);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(nodes, other);
    }
```

However this will only work if the implementations for `Node` also implement `equals(...)` and `hashCode(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@EqualsAndHashCode` from `lombok` at your `Node` (or `Label`) class.

Then you can add nodes to your `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Better not start using Lombok if you have yet no idea how equals and hashCode works in the first place, it will make it almost impossible to understand and debug it.